# How to resolve issue of AzureCliCredential?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli, azureclicredential

The following is my code and in linux I have logged in to azure via az login but when I try to run the below code it gives me an error that

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scan.py", line 1, in 
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential

I also installed the pip install azure-identity but its still the same.

```
#CODE#

from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient
import json


credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)
sub_list = subscription_client.subscriptions.list()

for sub in list(sub_list):
    subs_id = sub.subscription_id
    print(subs_id)
```

Comment: Just as a update the issue got resolved , I ran the code with python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad @[Ghostrider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14332374/ghost-rider) that you had resolved the issue yourself.

As you did not mention what version of python, you're using earlier, but for now resolved by using python 3.

I also run this code in my local VS Code with the Python 3.9 Version and got the successful result:

[image: VSCodeRun]

Also, observed the packages present in the code that the package `azure-identity` is supported from Python Version 3.6 or the latest versions, as given in the [Python Packages Library Official Site](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/).

Comment: I was running the file with normal python (filename) command so mostly it was some older 2 version of python , when I did python3 (filename) it started to work.

Comment: Yes @Ghostrider, Azure SDK Python packages support for Python 2.7 has ended 01 January 2022.

Comment: Thanks Hari will keep this into account while making future deployments.